# gnome-keyring-d uses CPU too much

Tags: 14.04, gnome, cpu, cpu-load, gnome-keyring

I'm using **14.04 LTS** and always monitoring how much CPU resources are used by processes. `gnome-keyring-d` always attracts my attention by using **too much CPU** - almost **10%**.

**After about 5 minutes OS starts, this huge CPU usage disappears.**

Is that normal? Same for you? If not, how can I resolve this issue?

*p.s. I always enter keyring into the prompt window as soon as OS starts.*